# Linq to Entities Select new List<int?> from Database inner select

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have a function that returns `IOrderedQueryable<Register>`. The Linq select looks like this (note:  have removed some fields for brevity). Once the base select is done I add additional search criteria to the linq so therefore it needs to remain as `IQueryable`. This allows for paging, sorting and additional filtering on these fields.

```
return Db.registers.Include(r => r.client_employee)
.Where(s => s.coid == coid)
.Select(row => new Register
{
    RegisterId = row.registerId,
    PersonId = row.emp_Id,
    .... other fields here ....
    
    ReportsToId = Db.client_employees.Where(c => c.client_ID == row.coid && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.position) && c.position.Equals(row.client_employee.reportsto,   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && c.active == 1 &&
    (c.dateterm == null || c.dateterm >= DateTime.Today)).DefaultIfEmpty().Select(c => (int?)c.emp_ID).FirstOrDefault(),
    
    .... more fields here ....
})
.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateFrom);
```

The `ReportsToId` is the issue I have. It is a `nullable<int>` and is the unique identifier of the client employee who has a `position` that is equal to the selected employee's `reportsto`. **Note:** The `reportsto` and `position` fields are strings.

I have read up on selecting data like this but it seems to take a really long time to return data regardless of how I structure this query.

I cannot use an inline expression tree Lambda like the below statement because this system is only in .Net 4.7 and I believe it requires 4.7.2 to allow this. I get the error:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operation

`Db.client_employees.First(c => c.position.Equals(row.client_employee.position, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && c.active == 1 && (c.dateterm == null || c.dateterm >= DateTime.Today))?.emp_ID`

**What I want**, in essence, is the next statement below, but I only want to call the Db Context once, and I am unable to use a *null propagating operation*.

The only way I have managed to get this to work with any semblance of success is like this, however this also takes a really long time to process.

```
ReportsToId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.client_employee.reportsto) && Db.client_employees.Any(c => c.position.Equals(row.client_employee.reportsto, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && c.active == 1 && c.client_ID == coid
        && (c.dateterm == null || c.dateterm >= DateTime.Today)) ?
        Db.client_employees.First(c => c.position.Equals(row.client_employee.reportsto, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && c.active == 1 && c.client_ID == coid
        && (c.dateterm == null || c.dateterm >= DateTime.Today)).emp_ID : (int?)null,
```

Can anyone shed some ideas on this issue. I am wondering if I need to get the powers that be to allow the whole project to be upgraded to .Net 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing and playing around with the query, I found the following issues with the above query.

- In the first line I don't need the `.Include(r => r.client_employee)`.
- When I looked at SQL profiler the
  `c.position.Equals(row.client_employee.position, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` part of the query was
  not even being added into the query. Therefore it was only adding
  `c.active == 1 && (c.dateterm == null || c.dateterm >= DateTime.Today)` part of the query to the SQL. I'm unsure why this was
  happening. Perhaps .Net 4.7 does not correctly parse this to SQL.
- When I changed the query to `ReportsToId = Db.client_employees.Where(c => c.client_ID == coid && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.position) && c.position.ToLower() == row.client_employee.reportsto.ToLower() && c.active == 1).Select(c => (int?)c.emp_ID).FirstOrDefault()` it gave the correct SQL in
  profiler. i.e. I used `ToLower()`
- Then I added some astute indexes and it went from about 13
  seconds for 100k rows to 1 second.

The ReportsToId select became:

```
ReportsToId = Db.client_employees.Where(c => c.client_ID == coid 
  && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.position) 
  && c.position.ToLower() == row.client_employee.reportsto.ToLower() 
  && c.active == 1).Select(c => (int?)c.emp_ID).FirstOrDefault()
```